# newbie: php preg_match_all not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to parse tags from a string like the following:

```
$string = "foo [cmd:tag1] bar [cmd:tag2] bla bla";
$pattern = "/\[cmd:(.+)\]/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$rc = $matches[0];
foreach($rc as $tag)
{
    print_r2($tag);
}
```

which will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [cmd:tag1] bar [cmd:tag2]
    [1] => 4
)
```

what is wrong in my syntax as i'm expecting the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [cmd:tag1]
    [1] => [cmd:tag2]
)
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
\[cmd:(.+?)\]
```

or use

```
\[cmd:([^\]]*)\]
```

Make your quantifier `*` non greedy by putting `?` ahead of it.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/23